# How do I roll-back to a previous Ubuntu kernel? (running Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, dependencies

I have a VPS server with a hosting company that I have ssh/root access. I recently tried to upgrade the kernel to the latest (4.18.5-041805-generic). I was running 4.4.0-169 and thought it was time to upgrade.

So I ran the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

After all of that, the kernel version still remained the same. So, after a search I found this set of instructions:

https://www.tecmint.com/upgrade-kernel-in-ubuntu/

I followed the instructions and attempted to install the latest kernel version. Near the end it generated an error indicating it was leaving it unconfigured, yet when I run "uname -rs" it lists the new kernel:

```
~$ uname -rs
Linux 4.18.5-041805-generic
```

However, now when I try to make sure everything else is also up to date again I get a dependency error:

---

```
~$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-headers-4.19.0-041900rc1-generic : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0) but it is not installable
 linux-image-unsigned-4.19.0-041900rc1-generic : Depends: linux-modules-4.19.0-041900rc1-generic but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

---

So, I wanted to go back to the old 4.4.0-169-generic  kernel but I cannot figure out how to do this. Every instruction that I can find in my searches says to use a keyboard shortcut to interrupt grub and then select a different kernel.

The problem is that I am running on a VPS cloud server and do not have a physical keyboard connected to the server. I only have the ssh window into the server to get anything done.

How do I delete the new kernel that generates the dependency issue and get back to booting with the previous kernel?

Comment: Don't mix apt repositories or packages made for other releases.

Answer (score 8):

Looking at for instance [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/110738), you can change the boot order of the two kernels from a terminal.  The heavily upvoted comment in that answer also suggests using the full name of the kernel, rather than its numerical index, for better stability.

In short:

1. `sudo view /boot/grub/grub.cfg` and copy the full name of your old
   kernel.
2. `sudo vi /etc/default/grub` and, at the top, change `GRUB_DEFAULT=0`
   to instead read `GRUB_DEFAULT=your_kernel_name_from_grub.cfg`, and
   save the change (you may like to keep a copy of the original file
   for safety).
3. `sudo update-grub`.

Then rebooting should bring you back to your older kernel.  If you wanted a quick fix, you could probably just change `GRUB_DEFAULT=0` to `GRUB_DEFAULT=1` in `/etc/default/grub` (and then `sudo update-grub` and reboot), but the above procedure is less brittle.

Comment: Is changing the boot order preferred to removing the new kernel, or is it hiding a problem? I'm not familiar with how kernel versions are managed, but what happens if a few months later another upgrade takes place and the one specified in GRUB is auto-removed?

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial you followed is better explained at the [Kernel: Mainline Builds - Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds).  See also Section 4 of that same Wiki article for removal instructions.

**Note**: *Just because there was a `dist-upgrade` doesn't necessarily mean there is a kernel upgrade in that upgrade.*  See the [Ubuntu Package repository: linux-image-generic](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/linux-image-generic)

Comment: Not exactly right... If you read that section on removing the offending kernel it indicates that once it is removed you are still dependent on the "GRUB boot menu" to change the booting kernel. ** I do NOT have access to the GRUB boot menu through a ssh window. That is only available by a keyboard shortcut (specifically the shift key during boot.) This is not a physical box on my desk, it is a cloud server. How can I alter the GRUB boot menu from a ssh window?

Comment: This is exactly correct.  Try [reading the manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man8/update-grub.8.html), or see [Phase 2 here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281119/how-do-you-run-update-grub).  Tip: Just because Ubuntu forces/prefers it's users to depend on GUI tools, using SSH requires you to learn without X.

Comment: I should also add that your cloud server instance still boots up with `grub` in some way as this is the preferred method in most Linux'es.  The post-install phase in apt  should have spit out a warning reminding you to run `update-grub`  Have a look at `/var/log/apt/history.log`